# Traceroute does not work, output is * * *

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, traceroute

I'm trying to check how many servers are between me and a domain server(google etc.). I'm using Linux (Ubuntu) subsystem on Windows. The `traceroute` command wasn't working, so I used `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install traceroute`. When I run it `traceroute -m 255 google.com` all I get is `***` through all hops. What am I doing wrong? I also tried it to run in school - eduroam and the result was the same.

For `traceroute -I www.google.com` I don't have enough privileges.

For `traceroute -I icmp google.com`, I get: "icmp: name or service not known".

Comment: I suspect you are having Windows firewall problems with the traceroute. As for -I, forget about it, WSL is not Linux.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I tried that on two different windows computers. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Seems to be a known problem. Some people have reported success after installing the inetutils version of traceroute and giving it the `-M icmp` option. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1930

Comment: @MarkPlotnick After many attempts it finally worked. I used `sudo apt install inetutils-traceroute` and `traceroute -M -icmp google.com`. Thank you!

Comment: @BostjanBolovi Cool. If you could, please answer this question in the text box at the bottom of this window, listing all the steps you took, in order to help other people who may have the same question.

Answer (score 2):

The solution turned out to be: `sudo apt install inetutils-traceroute` and `traceroute -M icmp google.com`.